# Subclauses in reported speech: subjunctive or indikative?

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech

The question is on the highlighted verb in this quote from Rotkäppchen.

> Es wird auch erzählt, dass einmal, als Rotkäppchen der alten Großmutter wieder Gebackenes **brachte**, ein anderer Wolf es angesprochen und vom Wege habe ableiten wollen. Rotkäppchen aber hütete sich und ging geradefort seines Wegs und sagte der Großmutter, dass es dem Wolf begegnet wäre, der ihm guten Tag gewünscht, aber so bös aus den Augen geguckt hätte: »Wenn’s nicht auf offener Straße gewesen wäre, er hätte mich gefressen.«

What is the significance of using *brachte* as opposed to *gebracht habe*?

I can imagine two possibilities.

- There was no choice:  *gebracht habe* in place of *brachte* would be ungrammatical.

  If this were so, the general rule might be something like this?

  > Where a dependent clause introduced by *dass* and constituting reported speech is itself made of a main clause and a dependent clause (introduced by *als*, *wenn*, *weil* etc.), the use of Konjunktiv I is limited to verbs in the main clause and the verbs in the dependent clause must be in the Indikativ.
- *gebracht habe* in place of *brachte* would still be grammatical, but some other reason recommends *brachte*.

  For example, the reason may be that the thing in focus was the wolf's wanting to speak to and lure away the girl and that the *als*-clause was merely setting the background.  So if the whole thing had been in focus, and the speaker wanted to distance himself from the content of the *als*-clause, i.e. imply that he was not even sure (or at any rate did not wish to assert) that Rotkäppchen had any second trip, he could have said *gebracht habe*.

Please let me know whether any of the above options is correct or something else is the case. I am interested in learning the most bookish (or highest register) of current German if it is different from spoken German.

Answer (score 1):

It would be grammatical to say

> Es wird auch erzählt, dass einmal, als Rotkäppchen der alten Großmutter wieder Gebackenes **gebracht habe**, ein anderer Wolf es angesprochen und vom Wege habe ableiten wollen.

It would not be archaic or in any way weird, it would just convey a different meaning.

When using the indicative, one states that there is no question that Rotkäppchen brought her grandmother cookies. It is given as a known fact — there might have been witnesses that saw her, or people know that she does that every day.

> Mein Biologielehrer hat gesagt, dass es keine Einhörner **gibt.**

The person saying this might have heard a wild story from someone revolving about unicorns, and is reassuring themselves by quoting a definite *fact* about the non-existence of unicorns.

Introducing a conjunctive would mean that the fact is (however slightly) questioned. So the above quote would now mean, that the speaker is not sure whether Rotkäppchen ever went to her grandmother to bring her cookies. The speaker assumes it to be the case, because otherwise they wouldn’t tell the story, but it can be questioned.

> Mein Biologielehrer hat gesagt, dass es keine Einhörner **gebe.**

If you say it like this, then the biology teacher might have stated the fact that unicorns don’t exist, but *you are questioning the fact* for a reason, like you believe in unicorns or you saw one.

So while in some languages indirect speech is grammatically required to be in a certain modus, German language distinguishes between statement of *facts* (indicative) and *assumptions* (conjunctive).

Comment: Thanks! On your question, I don't know that it is a Swiss or some other version. I got it from this Web page. http://www.grimmstories.com/de/grimm_maerchen/rotkaeppchen

Comment: There's a second difference that regards time. "Gebracht habe" implies that Rotkäppchen was approached after a successful deliverey, "brachte" means that she was on her way. Besides that, I don't think "als sie gebracht habe" is correct German but I have zero fact to back it up. Just a feeling.

Comment: Surely it doesn't always imply _questioning_ the claim. It can also be used to keep a safe distance from the claim, hold no liability, so to speak.

Comment: @Emanuel I have deleted my earlier comments because I see that you raised a new question addressing what I wanted to say. I am leaving a pointer to your question here, for others who may also want to follow through. http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24187/conjunctive-combined-with-als

Comment: @Emanuel Sorry for a double ping, I deleted the first comment, because brainfart. I see no temporal difference between preterite and conjunctive. To me, both imply she is on her way. And *als sie ihr etwas gebracht habe* is perfectly fine in my opinion.

Comment: @Jan ... maybe it's because you're from the South (if I remember correctly). To me it is absolutely no doubt that "Sie hat gebracht" is a completed action and "Sie habe gebracht" is just a form of that.

Comment: *So while in some languages indirect speech is grammatically required to be in a certain modus, German language distinguishes between statement of* facts *(indicative) and* assumptions *(conjunctive).* – Sorry, but that’s just plain wrong, in standard highest register German (what the question is asking for), the subjunctive is required in indirect speech. The speaker cannot use mode to distinguish between possibilities and facts, only between irrealities and everything else (by using the subjunctive II).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft That means you’re implying one need say *mein Lehrer sagt, dass Wasser bei 100 °C **siede***? I disagree.

Comment: @Jan: In standard highest-register German, yes. In colloquial German, the usage of modes is more or less arbitrary.

Comment: Es muss doch heißen "dass es keine Einhörner gäbe", nicht "gebe", auch wenn es ähnlich gesprochen wird, oder täusche ich mich? Der Hauptstoßrichtung stimme ich aber soweit zu. :)